# I made a dictionary, I am struggling with print x number of times that user inputs

Tags: python

This is my dictionary:

```
def get_dic(filename):
count = 0
db = {}
filename = "words.txt"


with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line:
            eng_words, spa_words = line.rstrip().split(":")
            key = eng_words
            val = spa_words.split(",")
            db[key] = val
            count += 1
            print(count, "entries found.")
            return db
```

this is the file it reads from and converts it to a dictionary:

```
library:la biblioteca
school:el colegio,la escuela
restaurant:el restaurante
movie theater:el cine
airport:el aeropuerto
museum:el museo
park:el parque
university:la universidad
office:la oficina,el despacho
house:la casa
```

Now I wanna call my db and make a "quiz" game using random() method after user inputs a number from 1 to 10. Since my list is only 10 lines.

```
import random

def main():

    db = get_dic(filename)
    random.shuffle(db)

    for keyword in db(10):
        display = "{}"

        print(display.format(keyword))
        userinput = input("Enter 1 equivalent Spanish word(s). Word [1]: ")
        print(db[keyword])
        print(" ")

        if userinput == (db[key]):
            print("correct!")
            correct += 1
```

If input is "5", how do I get the program to print 5 words?

And I wanna return the score "correct" into another function that is not main(). Which will later write the score to a seperate .txt file, Is this possible? Do I just "return correct" and call it in a function like usual? I've only seen codes call function in "def main():"

output example if input choosen is 2:

```
English word: museum
Enter 1 equivalent Spanish word(s). Word [1]: el museo
Correct!
---
English word: school 
Enter 2 equivalent Spanish word(s). Word [1]: el colegio 
Word [2]: la escuela 
Correct!
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Is it better now? @quamrana

Comment: Can you cut and paste from the question to a file and run it yet without indentation errors?

Comment: yes I can @quamrana

Comment: I'm pretty sure I cannot.

Comment: I am not getting any IndentationError when I copy and paste either function into python @quamrana

Comment: You are missing indentation in `get_dic` function @EggCoder

Comment: 1. your dict contains lists, but later on you compare its values with a string (userinput == (db[key]))
2. suffle intended for list and not a dictionary
3. What you meand by db(10)?

Comment: @DeepakGouda are you takling about my print and return lines? Thank you

Comment: @user3431635 thank you, I was hoping db(10) would pick words in the range of the 10 words from the dictionary?

Comment: Hope is never enough when it comes to programming. (Trial and error is a good substitute).

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you want. I ask the user how many rounds first. (I have not validated this input, though)

```py
def main():
    db = get_dic(filename)
    keys = list(db.keys())
    random.shuffle(keys)
    
    rounds = int(input('Enter a number of rounds (1-10): '))
    correct = 0
    for keyword in keys[:rounds]:
        print(keyword)
        userinput = input("Enter 1 equivalent Spanish word(s). Word [1]: ")
        print(db[keyword])
        print(" ")

        if userinput == (db[keyword]):
            print("correct!")
            correct += 1
    return correct

correct = main()
print(f'{correct} answers correct')
```

Comment: thank you! Could you explain what puttin rounds as [:rounds]: is it so it picks words from the second column if I remember correctly? Also it always return correct as 0 points should I assume it is because I messed my dictionary so the program dosen't recognize the words it is supposed to correct?

Comment: I get the user to input the number of rounds, so keys[:rounds] is a slice of the random selection of keys.

Comment: When I was testing it, I happened to get university and I input “la universidad” and it counted that as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t take into account that you seem to be allowing several different correct answers.

Comment: No worries I am trying to figure it out now, would the right choice be to create another for loop when it has two answers?

Comment: You could try: ‘if userinput in db[keyword]:’

Answer (score 0):

to validate the input you can also do

```py
def get_num(text,err_text,verify):
    try:
        the_input = int(input(text))
        if verift(the_input):
            return the_input
        else:
            print(err_text)
            return get_num(text,err_text)
    except:
        print(err_text)
        return get_num(text,err_text)

#...

rounds = get_num('Enter a number of rounds (1-10): ', 'please enter an integer between 1 and 10', verify=lambda x:x>0 and x <11)
```